# Fiddler doesn't show traffic from Cypress

Tags: fiddler, cypress

Background: I'm trying to send a request through `cy.request` and I get a different response from what I receive when I send a presumably similar request through PostMan. According to the debug information that Cypress writes to the console, I couldn't spot the difference. Therefore I wanted to look at Fiddler and see if I can spot the difference when looking at the raw requests side by side.

However, when I opened Fiddler I realized that I don't see any traffic from it, including the navigation to the home page using `cy.visit()`.

Any ideas why I can't see the traffic in Fiddler, and if there's some way to capture it?

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler is a proxy, it has to be explicitly used by an application, otherwise it will not be recogized by Fiddler.

There are three reasons that often cause that traffic is not visible in Fiddler:

1. The Windows application explicitly ignores the Windows/IE proxy settings. Usually such apps have an own proxy configuration. Configure it manually to use Fiddler. A common example of such an application is Firefox.
2. If you have activated the "Act as system proxy at startup" Fiddler changes the proxy settings while running. Any application that is already running when Fiddler starts may have already cached the old proxy configuration and therefore does not use Fiddler. Therefore start Fiddle before any program you want to capture.
3. The setting "Act as system proxy at startup" is AFAIK user specific, therefore any apps running on a different user or service account are not affected. You have to manually configure them to use Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

Cypress does not actually make an XHR request from the browser. Cypresd making the HTTP request from the Cypress Test Runner (in Node). So, you won’t see the request inside of your Developer Tools or filddler